# missing out the bin and the lib64 file when creating a virtual environment?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, virtualenv, missing-features

So I used `pip install virtualenv` and named it venv using `virtualenv venv`. Then I used `C:\Users\user\venv\Scripts\activate` to activate the virtualenv. I tried to install something and it didn't work. When I tried to find out why, I went into the folder of the virtual env and compared its contents to a tutorial I was watching before. I realized I am missing out the bin and the lib64 file that I think should normally be created and I have no idea why they are not being created. I am using python 3.6.2 and pip 20.3.3 on windows 10 with 64-bit

Comment: Can you elaborate on 'it didn't work'? Creating a [mcve] will make it easier to assist you.

Comment: In w32 directory `bin` is named `Scripts` and `lib64` is perhaps just `lib`.

Comment: Well import random honestly I don't know what else to provide because I have no problem what causes the problem. If you are on windows you should use  the commands I used and go into the folder, you will maybe miss the same problem because I searched around and I saw that others had the bin problem too. What makes me think is that I don't have the lib64 folder. In the tutorial I watched there was a lib folder and a lib64 folder so I am worried because even if there are different names on different systems in the end I am still missing one folder

Comment: @2five you should provide us the error message you are getting when trying to `pip install`. The lack of `bin` and `lib64` directories is likely not a problem - it's supposed to be like that on Windows. Some random suggestions: after activating the environment, try executing `pip -V` - it should mention the path to the interpreter inside the environment. Also, I remember I had some trouble activating virtual environments for a PowerShell shell - perhaps try using cmd.exe.